# Redirecting top when multiple CPU's shown

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, top

If you run `top`,  and then press `1`, it shows the breakdown of usage on each CPU.  How can I redirect this to a file?

I know I can do `top -n 1 > process.txt` but how can I get the `1` option in the file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing is to use the <kbd>W</kbd> key, which writes out your current choices to the file */home/yourname/.toprc*, so that, when you restart *top*,  it will keep the same configuration. So

```
   top
   1
   W
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now, when you restart with

```
   top -n 1 > my_outfile.txt
```

you will have maintained your configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you set `top` to default settings once you write the config file somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `mpstat` for getting CPU usage.

```
# mpstat -P 0,1,2,3
Linux 2.6.32-042stab078.28 (***.com)  01/27/2014      _i686_  (8 CPU)

04:06:39 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
04:06:39 PM    0    0.05    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.13    0.00   99.79
04:06:39 PM    1    0.05    0.00    0.04   28.78    0.00    0.00    0.19    0.00   70.93
04:06:39 PM    2    0.05    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.14    0.00   99.79
04:06:39 PM    3    0.05    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.13    0.00   99.79
```